# JSTL how to get dynamic token position

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have something like this:

**22-04-19 20:34:00!Color::blue!Manufacturer::Ford!Seats::4!Climatronic::yes**

I want to get the name of the category and its value (category::value).

The problem is that these positions (category::value) can shift places. ForTokens is index is not good here as it can be one or 10 different tokens.

```
<c:if test="${fn:contains(dataset, 'Color')}">
    <c:set var="color1" value="${fn:substringAfter(dataset, 'Color::')}" />
    <c:set var="color2" value="${fn:substringBefore(color1, '!')}" />
</c:if>
```

Something like this will also not work as it will print out the same value until the new one will appear (will fill out all null cells). I'm out of ideas.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Are you trying to extract the color from your string? Or are you trying to list all categories with their value?

Comment: @obourgain I'm trying to get the name and its value. But these change positions in the array so it's not constant.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the initial string and loop over each item to find the category you need:

```html
<c:set var="string1" value="22-04-19 20:34:00!Color::blue!Manufacturer::Ford!Seats::4!Climatronic::yes" />

<c:set var="categories" value = "${fn:split(string1, '!')}" />
<c:forEach var="category" items="${categories}" varStatus="status" >
    <c:if test="${status.index != 0}">
        <c:set var="decodedCategory" value="${fn:split(category,'::')}" />
        Category: <c:out value="${decodedCategory[0]}" />
        Value: <c:out value="${decodedCategory[1]}" />
        <br />
    </c:if>
</c:foreach>
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. This works similarly to what I made with ForTokens. Although I can't figure out how to put each value into a table cell without it being copied to the next empty cell (until new value appears).

| Entry date | Manufacturer | Seats |
| -------- | -------------- |-----|
| 22-04-19 20:34:00 | Ford | 4 |
| 22-04-19 21:04:00 | Ford | 4 |
| 22-04-19 22:44:00 | Toyota | 2 |

Comment: You are trying to do too many things in the JSP. You should prepare your data in Java in a data structure that will be easier to use in the JSP (for example storing the properties in a Map). Doing everything this in JSP is cumbersome, not effective, and not maintainable.